# FFmpeg filter_complex add watermark first then scale

Tags: ffmpeg

The following command scales the video and then adds watermark

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-2:480:flags=lanczos[scaled]; [scaled][1:v]overlay=40:H-h-40[out]"
```

However, I would like to reverse this so watermark is added first and then video is scaled as I'll be getting multiple resolutions out.

I tried the following but it throws `"Too many inputs specified for the "scale" filter"`

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]overlay=40:H-h-40[wm]; [wm][1:v]scale=-2:480:flags=lanczos[out]"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic syntax if you want to scale it thrice.

`-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=40:H-h-40,split=3[ol1][ol2][ol3];[ol1]scale=-2:480:flags=lanczos[out480];[ol2]scale=-2:360:flags=lanczos[out360];[ol3]scale=-2:240:flags=lanczos[out240]"`

After this, you need to map all these outputs for encoding.